# validate an XML schema against XMLSchema.xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xerces

I am trying to validate the simplest possible XSD file against [XMLSchema.xsd](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="a" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:schema>
```

To that end, I've downloaded file XMLSchema.xsd and pass it to my `org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver` to ensure that the locally provided `XMLSchema.XSD` is used and not one fetched over the Internet. The code runs with `Saxon-HE-9.4.jar` on my classpath.

However this fails with:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xs:schema'.

which appears to be related to a previous message (emitted by my custom `LSResourceResolver` subclass):

> Failed to read schema document '[...]XMLSchema.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.

When, however I comment out the entire `DOCTYPE` section in the `XMLSchema.XSD` file it is working.

I guess this means the parser can't handle the `DOCTYPE` and `ATTLIST` clauses in `XMLSchema.xsd`.

So I have two questions:

1. why is the parser failing to handle the `XMLSchema.xsd` XML prolog? and is there any way to fix this without having to edit the `XMLSchema.xsd` file?
2. if there is no way around #1, how can I download the `XMLSchema.xsd` file from http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd without the XML prolog so I don't have to edit manually. A simple `wget` fetches the XML prolog as well (which BTW does not appear when the link is visited with a browser).

This is really too large to provide an SSCCE but if anyone wants to have a look I'll provide a github repository with the test case.

Comment: Just wondering: are you using a DOM Document? If so on creation did you set validating to false or did you leave it at the default true?

Comment: @nablex yes the file is read as an `org.w3c.dom.Document`; on the `DocumentBuilderFactory` object I call: `setValidating(false);`

Comment: You've tagged this with both "saxon" and "xerces". Both of these provide schema validators, but you haven't made it clear which you are using. I get the impression from the error messages that you are using the xerces schema validator; so why have you tagged the question with "saxon"?

Comment: @MichaelKay you are right, the `Validator` I use is of class `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl`. Actually I am just doing a `Validator validator = schema.newValidator()` and since I only bring in saxon as a dependency I was assuming that the Saxon validator was used. Apparently saxon brings in Xerces and Xalan as transitive dependencies and so the Xerces validator ends up used. Is there a way to control which validator is created more explicitly? I've removed the saxon tag.

Comment: If you want to do schema validation with Saxon via JAXP interfaces then you can do it using the JAXP schema factory interface, but not by setting validation properties on the XML parser, because the Saxon validator isn't integrated with a parser, it's free-standing.

Answer (score 1):

If it's failing on the reference to XMLSchema.dtd, then one obvious solution (other than commenting out the DOCTYPE declaration, which you've already found) would be to download the DTD files (XMLSchema.dtd and datatypes.dtd) and supply them locally, as well.